# Best way to store array data as String in text file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm working on a (JavaScript/JQuery) project that requires me to save data as a file.

The data being stored is an array, which normally wouldn't be an issue because I can would just store it as a string and then split the string based on "," on loading the data again. However the array I need to store is an array of other arrays of data, some of which have a few layers of arrays.

My initial thought is to run a function which converts each array to a string starting at the lowest levels and then add some sort of identifier (eg '/////') between each entry to separate each array of data and use them as the thing to detect for a Split function. This however make the storing/loading of the data very complex and I was wondering if there is a better way of saving multi-layer array data in Javascript.

Comment: Convert the whole thing you want to save as a single object or array of objects and then run [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) on it. Save that string result to a file. Reverse the process to get your object/object array back (use JSON.parse to convert the string back to an object).

Comment: you can do JSON.stringify of the array which will JSON serialize to a string and then save it to a file, while retrieving you can use JSON.parse will deserialize.

Answer (score 5):

You can still save it as a string but the serialization should be something like [JSON](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp).

To convert to json (encode) use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify). This returns a string that you can save to the file:

```
var json_string = JSON.stringify(my_array);
```

Afterwards, to decode the string in the file (after reading it) use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```
var my_array = JSON.parse(json_string);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JSON.stringify` to convert a multi-level array to a string. And then you can use `JSON.parse` to convert it back to an array. Once you have the string you can save and restore it and use these methods to re-create the array.

```
a = [1, 2, [3, 4, [5, 6, [7, 8], 9]]]
> [1, 2, Array[3]]

s = JSON.stringify(a)
> "[1,2,[3,4,[5,6,[7,8],9]]]"

a2 = JSON.parse(s)
> [1, 2, Array[3]]
```